# Validation before Confirmation in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a code as follows:

```
 <p:commandButton value="#{actualProductionEntry.val}" onclick="confirmation.show()"/>
 <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Are you sure?" header="Confirm Submission"                                 severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">         
     <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" action="#   {actualProductionEntry.insert(login.userid,login.uid,login.dname,login.rptid)}"   update=":df:data :f1:p2 :dp:app"/>  
     <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />                 
 </p:confirmDialog>
```

Now, how can I do validation before confirmation without effecting my bean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PrimeFaces returns an `args.validationFailed` in the ajax response. You could check for that in the `oncomplete` attribute. Replace your `onclick` by

```
<p:commandButton ... oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) confirmation.show()" />
```

Alternatively, you could let the `<p:commandButton>` update the `<p:confirmDialog>` component and check in its `visible` attribute if according the `FacesContext` there's a postback and validation has not failed:

```
<p:commandButton ... update="confirmDialog" />
<p:confirmDialog ... visible="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}" />
```

Comment: What is 'args' here? How can I check it for several different controls(in case of solution-1)?

Comment: It's a JavaScript argument object which is implicitly available in PrimeFaces `oncomplete` attribute. The code is complete and as-is. You don't need to define it elsewhere or something. You can just see it in webbrowser's builtin JS debugger. Your second question is not clear. Different controls? What? Please elaborate.

Comment: ok, I have got it. It works nice. Thanx a ton. But my problem is that I have to show the validation messages before showing the confirmation dialog. Now I am showing the messages via  "<p:messages autoupdate="true"/>", but it is visible only after pressing the confirm button of confirmation dialog. How can I execute it whenever   args.validationFailed is happened?

Comment: hello, can anyone tell me how can I show the result of validation before showing my confirmation dialog??

Comment: It's strange. My answer shows ways how to hide the confirmation dialog when there are validation errors. And it still shows up in spite of validation errors? Perhaps there's more into your code.

Comment: No,the confirmation dialog can not be seen until n unless the validation errors are removed. Your code is working fine, but I have to show the error messages if there any before opening the confirmation dialog.. How can I do this?

Comment: Oh, just add the messages or the form to `update` attribute of command button, or use `<p:messages autoUpdate="true">`.

Comment: I have already done it. Here it is:                                                  <f:facet name="footer">
<p:commandButton value="#{actualProductionEntry.val}" onclick="confirmation.show()"/>
  <p:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{actualProductionEntry.delete}" rendered="#{actualProductionEntry.op}" update=":df:data :f1:p2"/><p:commandButton value="Reset" action="#{actualProductionEntry.reset}" update=":f1:p2" process="@this"/>  <p:messages autoupdate="true"/>
</f:facet> But it is becoming visible after executing the confirmation dialog!! Not before that ..!

Comment: But you're still opening it by `onclick`, not by `oncomplete` after a check on validation errors as provided in 1st part of my answer..?